# VSCode and Typescript: "No type definitions found for ..."

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, types, node-modules

I added a module that included types to my project but VSCode was unable to locate the types and gave me the error: "No type definitions found for ...".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try quitting VSCode and opening the project again.

If that doesn't work see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45575241/1736174

Comment: You can also reload window with `ctrl+r` or restart the TS server from the run prompt, without closing out vscode completely