# Why can't I always Go To Type Definition with my caret on a JS/TS parameter name in VS Code, and how can I work around it?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Let's say I have the following in VS Code:

```
type T1 = { x: number };
type T2 = { x: number } & { y: string };

function foo(arg1: T1, arg2: T2) {}
```

If I put cursor on `arg1` then go to type definition (using menu or a shortcut), it takes me to correct type definition for `T1`.  However, if I put a cursor on `arg2` and go to type definition, it pops up "no type definition found for 'arg2'.
It seems like for type that uses `&` I cannot get type definition.  I'm using VS Code 1.79.0 on Windows 10.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Edit: here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "include": [ "*.ts" ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Working for me in VSCode 1.79.0 and WebStorm 2023.1 on Linux. Maybe check your TS version, and .tsconfig settings?

Comment: I updated the question with my tsconfig.json.  Am i missing anything there?  Or did you mean different config file?  I couldn't find .tsconfig on my system.

Comment: My typescript version is 5.0.3.

Comment: Intersection types have been supported long before 5.0.3, and I don't see anything in your .tsconfig that would matter for this. Maybe try some of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65984276/vscode-and-typescript-no-type-definitions-found-for

Comment: Unfortunately those didn't work for me.  Maybe I should file a github issue for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this on VS Code 1.79.0 Ubuntu Snap with TypeScript 5.1.3. But personally, what I find curious is that the behaviour for arg1 exists at all. I wouldn't have expected it to be a thing.

Note that Go To Type Definition with caret on T2 type annotation of arg2 works fine, which I think is expected, and which I suggest you use as a workaround.